# Javascript - set multiple cookies in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, cookies, setcookie

the scenario is on the website, users can select stores multiple times and I want to grab all the stores user has selected and I want to use cookies for that.

I want to save cookies as JSON for example {"storeId", "0010"},{ "storeId", "0011"}, etc.

**so this code below:** it is not appending the cookies it is just overriding the value

```
function setCookieJson(name, value) {
    var cookie = [name, '=', JSON.stringify(value), '; domain=.', 
    window.location.host.toString(), '; path=/;'].join('');
    document.cookie = cookie;
} 

setCookieJson('storeId', storeId);
```

**the result I am getting from the above code is:**

storeId="0010"

and if change the store then

storeId="0011"

**However, the expected result should be**
{"storeId", "0010"},{ "storeId", "0011"}

Comment: *"users can select stores"* Stores? You could save in LS **(localStorage)** something like (JSON.stringify-ed OFC:)  `{storesIDs: [0010, 0011]}` etc... no need to repeat stuff

Comment: Your method should first check if the cookie already exists, and if so, grab the existing data so that you append to it and then save the new cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by implementing the cookie already exist check:

**code:**

```
function setCookieJson(name, value) {
    var cookieExisted = getCookie(name).replace(/"/g,"");
    var cookie;
    if (cookieExisted.length) {
        if (!cookieExisted.includes(value)) {
            cookie = [name, '=', JSON.stringify(value + ',' + cookieExisted), '; domain=.', window.location.host.toString(), '; path=/;'].join('');
        }
    } else {
        cookie = [name, '=', JSON.stringify(value), '; domain=.', window.location.host.toString(), '; path=/;'].join('');
    }
    document.cookie = cookie;
}
```